# Is this a valid for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

I'm currently learning c++ and i cant get my head around this syntax for the for loop.

I'm aware that `for(<T>: <V>)` (for-each) and the standard `for(init; cond; incr)` but i haven't come across the following before

```
for (char ch; cin>>ch && !isdigit(ch); )
```

If someone could shed some light onto it it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `init` is `char ch`, `cond` is `cin>>ch && !isdigit(ch)`, `incr` is empty.

Comment: ... so basically, it will sit in a loop, reading in characters, while the characters are not digits...

Comment: Some of use would perhaps use a `while` instead of a `for` when the incr part is empty.

Comment: @BoPersson Probably your style choice on that is more common than my choice.  But I think my choice leads to more readable and maintainable code.  I very often leave the incr part empty.  Moving the declaration outside the loop statement is worse.  `while` should be used only when it is a better fit to the situation (doesn't need anything extra above the loop that belongs in the loop).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (char ch; cin>>ch && !isdigit(ch);    )
     ^^ A ^^  ^^^^^^^^ B ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^ C ^
```

A: Is the init section but in this case it only declared a `char` named `ch`
B: Is the condition section executed on each iteration

- It starts be taking a single character as input and then continues looping if it is not a digit

C: Is the increment section but is empty, the condition section is relied upon to get the next input (i.e., the *increment*) and cause the loop's termination

Comment: Conceptually `cin>>ch` is the "increment" part of the loop.  It is the code that advances you to the next step of the loop.  But it can't be expressed as the incr part of a `for` statement for two reasons:  This loop needs that action at the beginning of the first iteration in addition to between iterations.  The result of the operation (state of cin) is part of the condition.  That leads to a common idiom of experienced C programmers of mixing the conceptual increment operation in as part of the syntactic condition part.

Comment: @JSF Yes, you're absolutely correct. I updated the wording for the explanation of part 'C'.

Answer (score 3):

This is the same syntax as your second example:

```
for (  init ;         cond           ; incr)
for (char ch; cin>>ch && !isdigit(ch);     )
```

This just default-initializes a `char`, then reads a new value in and ensures it's a digit each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (char ch; cin>>ch && !isdigit(ch); )
```

Is your standard 3 part for loop. `char ch;` declares a `char` called `ch`.  The condition of the the loop is the result of `cin>>ch` logically and with `!isdigit(ch)` and there is nothing being incremented.

The result of this for loop is it will read in input until the input is a digit or it reaches the end if the input.

A for loop does not need to have something in each part.  As an extreme if you write `for(;;)` you would have a loop that runs forever.

Answer (score 1):

It is.

The first value is simply an initialization value (`char ch` will remain unchanged, but simply be defined).

The second value is a value that has to be true for the loop to end (condition) - so until `cin >> ch` is not `null` (it gains a value) and until `ch` isn't a digit, it will run.

The third parameter is an increment, that is a `void` in your case, so nothing happens.

EDIT: I remember back in C++ classes in 1st year of college, my teacher would do something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; cout << array[i++]);
```

and basically shrinking the code by a line.